# Printing a View within a page of html Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I can't seem to get this to work. I've used the below in tpl.php and it works fine, however this is the first time I've tried to use it to output a view.

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'sc_file_view-block_4');
               print $block['content']; ?>
```

The "sc_file_view-block_4' is the Block ID/ what shows up when I hover over the block in the block admin page. I get no errors generated but no output either.

I've also tried:

```
$viewName = 'sc_file_view';
$displayId = 'sc_file_view-block_4';
print views_embed_view( $viewName, $displayId);
```

and I tried just using block_4 as the displayId as well.

I have a tab system built in html w/css and jquery show/hide and hash tags being appended to the url and all that works fine....and I've tried some basic php to make sure the hidden value in the css wasn't affecting the content getting rendered in the first place.

Any ideas? I just want to render the block display of a view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work by updating all modules and core to 6.28 (from 6.26) Don't know why that code would not have worked. I must have had some specific version of some module that conflicted with some other more updated module!

Anyway, what worked just fine was:

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'sc_file_view-block_4');
               print $block['content']; ?>
```